# MongoDB Get average of group considering rank of document

Tags: mongodb, group-by, average, aggregation-framework, rank

I have documents getting in order like:

```
{ 
   "_id": "abcde1",
   "value" : 300
},
{ 
   "_id": "abcde2",
   "value" : 200
},
{ 
   "_id": "abcde3",
   "value" : 400
},
{ 
   "_id": "abcde4",
   "value" : 500
},
{ 
   "_id": "abcde5",
   "value" : 600
}
```

i.e, 
I want average of "_id" of first 2, first 4 and all 5 documents matching like in single query:

```
{
    "value_2" : 250,   // Average of first 2 documents
    "value_4" : 350,    // Average of first four documents
    "value_5" : 400     // Average of all 5 documents
}
```

Is it possible to Group documents based on rank of document.

I can do 3 results in 3 separate queries. Is it possible in single query?

Comment: I suppose the current documents are as a result of a prior pipeline. The general idea I can think of is to add a computed field to the documents which holds the document rank, aggregate the different sums and key counts within the preceding `$group` pipeline using the `$cond` tenary conditions on the rank e.g `"value_2_total": {
                "$sum": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$lte": ["$rank", 2] },
                        "$value",
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }`

Comment: Once you get the ranked values sums and key counts you can then calculate the averages in a `$project` pipeline using the arithmetic operators e.g. `"value_2" : { "$divide": ["$value_2_total", "$value_2_count"] }`

Comment: @chridam: Yeah. I know how to get next one. But I am not able to get $rank. Is there any way to get rank when we sort documents.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way currently. There's a JIRA for this feature request though https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8065

Comment: Just out of interest, do the previous pipelines have an `$unwind` stage? You could use the `includeArrayIndex` option to get the rank field?

Comment: @chridam: No. Previous stage has `$sort` stage.  Then I need to group by numbers. I think as of now, I need to use 3 different queries only.

Comment: Might have a workaround. Posting it as an answer that you may consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running the following pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // previous pipeline here
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "values": { "$push": "$value" }                
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": { "path": "$values", "includeArrayIndex": "rank"  } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "value_2_sum": {
                "$sum": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$lt": ["$rank", 2] },
                        "$values",
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            "value_2_count": {
                "$sum": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$lt": ["$rank", 2] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            "value_4_sum": {
                "$sum": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$lt": ["$rank", 4] },
                        "$values",
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            "value_4_count": {
                "$sum": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$lt": ["$rank", 4] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            "value_5": { "$avg": "$values" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "value_2" : { "$divide": ["$value_2_sum", "$value_2_count"] },   // Average of first 2 documents
            "value_4" : { "$divide": ["$value_4_sum", "$value_4_count"] },    // Average of first four documents
            "value_5" : 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Do you know how to push all documents in one document and then unwind again? I have updated question again. So "_id" is different, is there any way to push all documents in one document and then unwind them with an index?

Comment: Yes, you just have to specify an `_id` value of `null` to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole. On a side note, it is [not an acceptable practice here on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions/) to alter questions significantly when an answer has been submitted before

Comment: This really helped me. It can be used until official support for "$rank". Sorry, if I confused it. Actually while posting question, I forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) aggregation stage:

```
// { _id: "abcde1", value: 300 }
// { _id: "abcde2", value: 200 }
// { _id: "abcde3", value: 400 }
// { _id: "abcde4", value: 500 }
// { _id: "abcde5", value: 600 }
db.collection.aggregate([

  { $facet: {
    value_2: [ { $limit: 2 }, { $group: { _id: null, value_2: { $avg: "$value" } } } ],
    value_4: [ { $limit: 4 }, { $group: { _id: null, value_4: { $avg: "$value" } } } ],
    value_5: [ { $limit: 5 }, { $group: { _id: null, value_5: { $avg: "$value" } } } ]
  }},
  // {
  //   value_2: [ { _id: null, value_2: 250 } ],
  //   value_4: [ { _id: null, value_4: 350 } ],
  //   value_5: [ { _id: null, value_5: 400 } ]
  // }

  { $set: {
    value_2: { $first: "$value_2.value_2" },
    value_4: { $first: "$value_4.value_4" },
    value_5: { $first: "$value_5.value_5" }
  }}
])
// { "value_2" : 250, "value_4" : 350, "value_5" : 400 }
```

The `$facet` stage allows us to run multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents. Each sub-pipeline has its own field in the output document where its results are stored as an array of documents.

Each field is thus produced by its own aggregation pipeline whose first stage is a simple `$limit`, followed by a `$group` stage that'll produce the `$avg` (average) of all considered documents.

The second part of the pipeline (the `$set` stage) is just there to clean-up the `$facet` output to the format you wished for.